# How to add a button to update another model in Django UpdateView

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

I have ListView that shows list of Person Models for a Home Moldel. When I click on a respective link for a Person, an UpdateView is called for the Person. I can click a "Cancel" or "Update" button once I am view for the Person. When I click either buttons, I am brought back to the ListView of the Persons. Now, I want to add another button "Update Another". This button should bring the next Person in the ListView that should be updated. See, example below:

```
ListView --Template (Project)
  Person1    <link1>
  Person2    <link2>
  Person3    <link3>
  Person4    <link4>

UpdateView --Template (Person1)  
    forms fields....
    [Cancel]  [Update] [Update Another]
```

If a user clicks on "Update Another", the user should be seeing the UpdateView --Template for Person2 and so... It could be cyclic.